# Java - Convert list of objects to map of map data structure

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I am trying to convert List of objects data structure in to Map of Maps.

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>>
```

String is sports variable

Integer is orderId.

My logic returned below value  as shown below. I am looking for better way of achieving this.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Student {    
    private String name;
    private int rollno;
    private int studentage;
    private String sports;
    private int orderId;
}   

@Data
@Builder
public class StudentModel {
    private String name;
    private int rollno;
    private int studentage;
    private String sports;
}
```

Created same data and added to list:

```
arraylist.add(new Student(223, "Zebra", 26, "cricket", 1));
arraylist.add(new Student(245, "Rahul", 24, "cricket", 2));
arraylist.add(new Student(209, "Ajeet", 32, "cricket", 3));
arraylist.add(new Student(140, "Abhay", 28, "basketball", 4));
arraylist.add(new Student(270, "Ranger", 29, "basketball", 5));
arraylist.add(new Student(250, "Ranger1", 39, "basketball",6));
Collections.sort(arraylist, Comparator.comparing(Student::getOrderId));
```

My expected output:

```
{
 cricket={
     1=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=223, name=Zebra, studentage=26), 
     2=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=245, name=Rahul, studentage=24), 
     3=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=209, name=Ajeet, studentage=32)
     }, 
 basketball={
     4=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=140, name=Abhay, studentage=28), 
     5=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=270, name=Ranger, studentage=29), 
     6=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=250, name=Ranger1, studentage=39)
     }
 }
```

Logic written:

```
public Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> studentModel() {
    Map<Integer, StudentModel> studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Student student : arraylist) {
        StudentModel studentModel = StudentModel.builder().name(student.getName)
        .rollno(student.getRollno)
        .studentage(student.getStudentage)
        .sports(student.getSports)
        studentMap.put(studentModel.getOrderId, studentModel);
        inputMap.put(student.getSports, studentMap);
    }
 }
```

Above logic is returning below result:

```
 {
 cricket={
     1=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=223, name=Zebra, studentage=26), 
     2=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=245, name=Rahul, studentage=24), 
     3=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=209, name=Ajeet, studentage=32),
     4=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=140, name=Abhay, studentage=28), 
     5=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=270, name=Ranger, studentage=29), 
     6=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=250, name=Ranger1, studentage=39)
     }, 
 basketball={
     1=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=223, name=Zebra, studentage=26), 
     2=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=245, name=Rahul, studentage=24), 
     3=Student(sports=cricket, rollno=209, name=Ajeet, studentage=32),
     4=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=140, name=Abhay, studentage=28), 
     5=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=270, name=Ranger, studentage=29), 
     6=Student(sports=basketball, rollno=250, name=Ranger1, studentage=39)
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My expected output and actual output from code are different

Comment: Check expected output: Above logic is returning below result: values in above code

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using only a single instance/memory of `studentMap` for each entry of `inputMap`, hence you see all 6 student entries against each 'sport' key because each of those `inputMap` entry values are pointing to same reference value of `studentMap` and thus observes changes done by any sports type key.

What you want to do here is to create new memory of `studentMap` for each type of 'sport', so. You can try doing something like this:

```
public Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> studentModel() {

    Map<Integer, StudentModel> studentMap;
    Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Student student : arraylist) {
        StudentModel studentModel = StudentModel.builder().name(student.getName)
        .rollno(student.getRollno)
        .studentage(student.getStudentage)
        .sports(student.getSports)

        // This would create new memory for each type of sport
        studentMap = inputMap.getOrDefault(student.getSports, new LinkedHashMap<Integer, StudentModel>());
        studentMap.put(studentModel.getOrderId, studentModel);
        inputMap.put(student.getSports, studentMap);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Cool. This worked for me. Thanks
Can you explain what do you mean by "you are using only a single instance/memory of studentMap for each entry of inputMap"

Comment: @sudhir What I meant by that is all the inputMap values are pointing to same reference for Map<Integer, StudentModel> because clearly studentMap was created just once. Hence, whenever studentMap gets updated, its reference starts reflecting those changes wherever we are using it. As a result, output had 6 student records against each sports type.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new map for each sport:

```
public Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> studentModel() {
    Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Student student : arraylist) {
        StudentModel studentModel = StudentModel.builder().name(student.getName)
        .rollno(student.getRollno)
        .studentage(student.getStudentage)
        .sports(student.getSports)
        // create a new map and insert it into the outer map if it's not already there
        Map<Integer, StudentModel> studentMap = inputMap.computeIfAbsent(student.getSports, k -> new LinkedHashMap<>());
        studentMap.put(studentModel.getOrderId, studentModel);
    }
 }
```

Unrelated to the issue but fields should be accessed with getter methods, e.g. instead of `student.getSports` you should have a private `sports` field with a `getSports()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The groupingBy method does exactly what you need. You want to group the students in your original arraylist based on their sport:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> inputMap = arraylist.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSports));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using same instance of student map in both the category.

### here is your code

```
 public Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> studentModel() {
    Map<Integer, StudentModel> studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Student student : arraylist) {
        StudentModel studentModel = StudentModel.builder().name(student.getName)
                .rollno(student.getRollno)
                .studentage(student.getStudentage)
                .sports(student.getSports)
        studentMap.put(studentModel.getOrderId, studentModel);//logical error here
        inputMap.put(student.getSports, studentMap);//error here
    }
}
```

### use below code for desired result

```
public Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> studentModel() {
    Map<Integer, StudentModel> studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<Integer, StudentModel>> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Student student : arraylist) {
        if (inputMap.get(student.getSports())==null){
            studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }else{
            studentMap = inputMap.get(student.getSports());
        }
        StudentModel studentModel = StudentModel.builder().name(student.getName)
                .rollno(student.getRollno)
                .studentage(student.getStudentage)
                .sports(student.getSports)
        studentMap.put(studentModel.getOrderId, studentModel);//error here
        inputMap.put(student.getSports, studentMap);//error here
    }
}`
```